Solve $f’’(x) = f(1 - x) - \frac{1}{2} (f(0) + f(1)) + \left(1 - \frac{x}{2}\right)f’(1 - x)$.
I was solving a combinatorics problem about expected values. To do so, I needed to solve this equation: Find the function $f: [0, 1] \to (-\infty, \infty)$ such that $$f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \left(1 - \frac{x}{2}\right) \int_0^1 f(t)dt + \left(1 - \frac{x}{2}\right) \int_0^{1-x} f(t)dt.$$
By taking the second derivative of both sides, I believe that we get $f’’(x) = f(1 - x) - \frac{1}{2} (f(0) + f(1)) + \left(1 - \frac{x}{2}\right)f’(1 - x)$. Please check this, I am not too good with computations.
I’m not sure what to do after. I haven’t actually taken a differential equations course, so I don’t know if this is trivial, impossible to solve, or a reasonable problem. Any solutions?

(i) I've obtained $f''(x)=f(1-x)+\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)f'(1-x).$ (ii) What do you mean by "$f:[0,1]\to\color{\red}{\infty}$"? The codomain of $f$ must be a set.

Sorry, I meant $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Notice that $f(0) = 2 \int_0^1 f(t)dt$. Furthermore, if you assume $f$ is symmetric about $x = \frac{1}{2}$, you have $f''(x) = f(x) - f(0) + (1-\frac{x}{2})f'(x)$, which seems to be some sort of Hermite equation https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermiteDifferentialEquation.html
